# ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener when running JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

In my Intelly Idea's Gradle-based project (Java Spring Boot ver. '2.0.3.RELEASE') when i try to debug an unit-test i'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:45)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 16 more
```

Gradle edition is 4.8

Gradle dependecies are:

> ```
> testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
> testCompile(
>         'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
> )
> testRuntime(
>         'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0',
>         'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.1.0',
>         'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.1.0',
>         'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.1.0'
> )
> ```

What setting(s) am I missing and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you use both JUnit 4 and 5 in your project? Launchers are normally not needed if you run the recent IntelliJ IDEA version: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea.

Comment: Actually this is a new project but how can i remove any relations to JUnit4?

Comment: Remove `testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")` and reimport.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help(

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? If it's the latest, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
gradle test
```

on the command line. This should show more verbose output to help diagnose the problem.